# How , to avoid vertical straight to overlap the others labels in LaTeX chronosys

Tags: time, time-series, latex, timeline

I´m trying to follow the documentation of chronosys LaTeX package, to solve my issue to avoid vertical straight to overlap the others labels, but I cannot go ahead!

[image]

My code in LaTeX is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}

\startchronology[startyear=1980]
\chronoevent{1982}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{ARCH} $\Rightarrow$ \newline Robert Engle~\cite{engle}}}
\chronoevent[markdepth=50pt, ifcolorbox = true, colorbox = white]{1986}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{GARCH} $\Rightarrow$ \textit{Tim Bollerslev}~\cite{bollerslev}}}
\chronoevent[markdepth=250pt]{1986}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{IGARCH} $\Rightarrow$ \textit{Tim Bollerslev e R. Engle}~\cite{englebollerslev}}}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

That is the result:

[image]

I tryed to insert colorbox=white, but I don´t know if I am is in the correct way...

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the events, so you won't draw the bottom even on top of the other:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}

\startchronology[startyear=1980]
\chronoevent{1982}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{ARCH} $\Rightarrow$ \newline Robert Engle~\cite{engle}}}
\chronoevent[markdepth=250pt]{1986}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{IGARCH} $\Rightarrow$ \textit{Tim Bollerslev e R. Engle}~\cite{englebollerslev}}}
\chronoevent[markdepth=50pt]{1986}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{GARCH} $\Rightarrow$ \textit{Tim Bollerslev}~\cite{bollerslev}}}

\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

[image]